# Backwards compatibility of ARM ISA Versions (particularly when using QEMU w/ KVM acceleration)

Tags: arm, virtualization, qemu, arm64

I'm working on using QEMU w/ [KVM acceleration](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/KVM) to test various arm64 binaries. My host CPU is ARMv8.5 the guest CPU I'm trying to emulate is an ARM Cortex-A53 (ARMv8). Few questions:

1. **Will these binaries be backward compatible and allow KVM acceleration?** (this might be a yes and no)
2. **Broadly speaking does ARM have any guarantees of backward compatibility?** Doesn't seem like this is the case which makes trying to design a KVM-accelerated emulation system rather difficult.

Comment: What instructions in particular are you worried about and what did arms documentation say when you looked this up?

Comment: i cant imagine the word guarantee would ever be used.  Quite the opposite there is probably a disclaimer that a particular core might not actually meet the architectural reference manual specifications, and arm is not responsible for your product if there turns out to be a bug....But I have not seen what their legal agreements say...Would never expect to see the word guarantee.  that would make the price of the core impractical.

Comment: What do you mean by "these binaries"? Your KVM, or the binaries you're trying to run? And backwards compatibility _of what_? Do you want new CPUs to be compatible with software compiled for old CPUs, or do you want software compiled for new CPUs to be compatible with old CPUs?

Comment: @Siguza sorry for the lack of clarification. New CPUs to be compatible with software compiled for old CPUs. I basically want to emulate older architecture chips on single-board computers.